# Eclipse debug point pointing to jar file in .M2/Repository instead of source

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm facing eclipse debug issue, I have a source(java sources from external folder) link to eclipse project and I deleted the respective jar file from web-inf\lib folder.

I build the project and kept a debug point, but the debug is somehow going to the corresponding jar file which is in .M2 repository and debug happening in that file.

Note: It is not a maven project.

Comment: Can you find the JAR in _Run > Debug Configurations..._ in the tab _Classpath_? If yes, can it be removed or comes it from the build path of the project?

Comment: @howlger, Thank you for your effort, Solved the issue by deleted the pom.xmls and Meta-inf folder.